# stripe token warning message

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I have `PHP Notice:  Undefined index: stripeToken` appear on my formular.

it's in relation `$_POST['stripeToken']`

```
 if (!isset($stripe_payment_intent_id)) {
    $description = 'Order date time : ' . date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

    $token  = $_POST['stripeToken'];

    $params = [
        'amount' => $total_amount,
        'currency' => $currency,
        'source' => $token,
        'setup_future_usage' => 'off_session',
        'description' => $description,
        'capture_method' => $capture_method,
        'metadata' => $metadata
    ];

    $this->intent = PaymentIntent::create($params);

   // $this->event_log($customer_id, "page create intent", json_encode($params), $this->intent);
    $stripe_payment_intent_id = $this->intent->id;

    unset($_SESSION['stripe_payment_intent_id']);
  }
```

Do you know how to resolve this problem ?
Maybe something must be added inside as hidden fields to take in consideration the `$_POST` ?

Tk

there my javascript

```
       public function getSubmitCardDetailsJavascript($intent = null) 
    {
      $stripe_publishable_key = $this->public_key;

//        $intent_url = tep_href_link("ext/modules/payment/stripe_sca/payment_intent.php", '', 'SSL', false, false);
      $intent_url = ''; // return url

      $js = <<<EOD
<style>
#stripe_table_new_card #card-element {
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
</style>
<script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script>
<script>
$(function() {
    $('[name=checkout_confirmation]').attr('id','payment-form');

    var stripe = Stripe('{$stripe_publishable_key}');
    var elements = stripe.elements();

    // Create an instance of the card Element.
    var card = elements.create('card', {hidePostalCode: true});
    
    // Add an instance of the card Element into the `card-element` <div>.
    card.mount('#card-element');

    $('#payment-form').submit(function(event) {
        var \$form = $(this);

        // Disable the submit button to prevent repeated clicks
        \$form.find('button').prop('disabled', true);

        var selected =  $("input[name='stripe_card']:checked"). val();
        var cc_save = $('[name=card-save]').prop('checked');
        try {
            if ((selected != null && selected != '0') || cc_save) {
                // update intent to use saved card, then process payment if successful
                updatePaymentIntent(cc_save,selected);
            } else {
                // using new card details without save
                processNewCardPayment();
            }
        } catch ( error ) {
            \$form.find('.payment-errors').text(error);
        }

        // Prevent the form from submitting with the default action
        return false;
    });

    if ( $('#stripe_table').length > 0 ) {
        if ( typeof($('#stripe_table').parent().closest('table').attr('width')) == 'undefined' ) {
          $('#stripe_table').parent().closest('table').attr('width', '100%');
        }

        $('#stripe_table .moduleRowExtra').hide();

        $('#stripe_table_new_card').hide();
        $('#card-element').prop('id','new-card-element');
        $('#save-card-element').prop('id','card-element');

        $('form[name="checkout_confirmation"] input[name="stripe_card"]').change(function() {

            if ( $(this).val() == '0' ) {
                stripeShowNewCardFields();
            } else {
                if ($('#stripe_table_new_card').is(':visible')) {
                    $('#card-element').prop('id','new-card-element');
                    $('#save-card-element').prop('id','card-element');
                }
                $('#stripe_table_new_card').hide();

            }
            $('tr[id^="stripe_card_"]').removeClass('moduleRowSelected');
            $('#stripe_card_' + $(this).val()).addClass('moduleRowSelected');
            });

        $('form[name="checkout_confirmation"] input[name="stripe_card"]:first').prop('checked', true).trigger('change');

        $('#stripe_table .moduleRow').hover(function() {
            $(this).addClass('moduleRowOver');
        }, function() {
            $(this).removeClass('moduleRowOver');
        }).click(function(event) {
            var target = $(event.target);

            if ( !target.is('input:radio')) {
                $(this).find('input:radio').each(function() {
                    if ( $(this).prop('checked') == false ) {
                        $(this).prop('checked', true).trigger('change');
                    }
                });
            }
            });
    } else {
        if ( typeof($('#stripe_table_new_card').parent().closest('table').attr('width')) == 'undefined' ) {
            $('#stripe_table_new_card').parent().closest('table').attr('width', '100%');
        }
    }
    function stripeShowNewCardFields() {
        $('#card-element').attr('id','save-card-element');
        $('#new-card-element').attr('id','card-element');

        $('#stripe_table_new_card').show();
    }
    function updatePaymentIntent(cc_save,token){
        // add card save option to payment intent, so card can be saved in webhook
        // or customer/payment method if using saved card
        $.getJSON( "{$intent_url}",{"id":$('#intent_id').val(),
                                    "token":token, 
                                    "customer_id": $('#customer_id').val(), 
                                    "cc_save": cc_save},
        function( data ) {
            if (data.status == 'ok') {
                var selected = $("input[name='stripe_card']:checked"). val();

                if (selected == null || selected == '0') {
                    processNewCardPayment();
                } else {
                    processSavedCardPayment(data.payment_method);
                }
            } else {
                var \$form = $('#payment-form');
                \$form.find('button').prop('disabled', false);
                $('#card-errors').text(data.error);    
            }
        });
    }
    function processNewCardPayment() {
        stripe.handleCardPayment(
            $('#secret').val(), card, {
              payment_method_data: {
                billing_details: {
                    name: $('#cardholder-name').val(),
                    address: {
                        city: $('#city').val(),
                        line1: $('#line1').val(),
                        postal_code: $('#postal_code').val(),
                        state: $('#state').val(),
                        country: $('#country').val()
                    },
                    email: $('#email_address').val()
                }
              }
            }
        ).then(function(result) { 
            stripeResponseHandler(result);
        });
    }
    function processSavedCardPayment(payment_method_id) {
        stripe.handleCardPayment(
            $('#secret').val(), 
            {
              payment_method: payment_method_id
            }
        ).then(function(result) { 
            stripeResponseHandler(result);
        });
    }
    function stripeResponseHandler(result) {
        var \$form = $('#payment-form');
        if (result.error) {
            $('#card-errors').text(result.error.message);
            \$form.find('button').prop('disabled', false);
        } else {
            $('#card-errors').text('Processing');

            // Insert the token into the form so it gets submitted to the server
            \$form.append($('<input type="hidden" name="stripeIntentId" />').val(result.paymentIntent.id));
            // and submit
            \$form.get(0).submit();
        }
    }
});
</script>
EOD;

      return $js;
    }
```

Note :

`$_POST['stripeToken']` is essential or create an error if this is used `$_POST['stripeToken'] ??'';`

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught (Status 400) (Request req_IX420AP8Wy1zL4) No such source: ''
  thrown in /var/www/cl....../vendor/stripe/stripe-php/lib/Exception/ApiErrorException.php on line 38
```

HTML code

```
<form name="checkout" action="https://www.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.com/Process" method="post" id="payment-form" class="form-inline" role="form" onsubmit="return checkCheckBox(this)">
    <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="separator"></div>
    <div class="card moduleCheckoutConfirmationPaymentInformationCard">
        <div class="card-header moduleCheckoutConfirmationPaymentInformationCardHeader"><strong>Paiement destiné à :</strong></div>
        <div class="card-block moduleCheckoutConfirmationPaymentInformationCardBlock">
            <div class="separator"></div>
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <div class="">
                    Stripe paiement : Veuillez remplir les champs
                    <div class="separator"></div>
                    <input type="hidden" id="intent_id" value="pi_1I5SZvKZUkuP7mZSeaBMX7uN" /><input type="hidden" id="secret" value="pi_1I5SZvKZUkuP7mZSeaBMX7uN_secret_jbzEVl5gvWLdp1oXjByDylWwH" />
                    <div id="stripe_table_new_card">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="cardholder-name" class="control-label">Nom du propriétaire</label>
                            <div><input type="text" id="cardholder-name" class="form-control" value="xxxxxxxxxxxx" required="" /></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="separator"></div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="card-element" class="control-label">Type de carte</label>
                            <div id="card-element" class="col-md-5 StripeElement StripeElement--empty">
                                <div
                                    class="__PrivateStripeElement"
                                    style="margin: 0px !important; padding: 0px !important; border: none !important; display: block !important; background: transparent !important; position: relative !important; opacity: 1 !important;"
                                >
                                    <iframe
                                        frameborder="0"
                                        allowtransparency="true"
                                        scrolling="no"
                                        name="__privateStripeFrame1055"
                                        allowpaymentrequest="true"
                                        src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/elements-inner-card-bcxxxxxxxxxxxxxaxxxxxxxxxxx.html#wait=false&amp;hidePostalCode=true&amp;rtl=false&amp;componentName=card&amp;keyMode=live&amp;apiKey=pk_live_qlbcxxxxxxxxxxxxxaxxxxxxxxxxxjUOs5yndgxxxxxxxxxxx&amp;origin=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.xxxxxxxx.com&amp;referrer=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.xxxxxxxxxxx.com%2Findex.php%2FCheckout%2FConfirmation&amp;controllerId=__privateStripeController1051"
                                        title="Cadre de saisie sécurisé pour le paiement par carte"
                                        style="
                                            border: none !important;
                                            margin: 0px !important;
                                            padding: 0px !important;
                                            width: 1px !important;
                                            min-width: 100% !important;
                                            overflow: hidden !important;
                                            display: block !important;
                                            user-select: none !important;
                                            transform: translateZ(0px) !important;
                                            height: 16.8px;
                                        "
                                    ></iframe>
                                    <input
                                        class="__PrivateStripeElement-input"
                                        aria-hidden="true"
                                        aria-label=" "
                                        autocomplete="false"
                                        maxlength="1"
                                        style="
                                            border: none !important;
                                            display: block !important;
                                            position: absolute !important;
                                            height: 1px !important;
                                            top: 0px !important;
                                            left: 0px !important;
                                            padding: 0px !important;
                                            margin: 0px !important;
                                            width: 100% !important;
                                            opacity: 0 !important;
                                            background: transparent !important;
                                            pointer-events: none !important;
                                            font-size: 16px !important;
                                        "
                                    />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div id="card-errors" role="alert" class="messageStackError payment-errors"></div>
                    </div>
                    <input type="hidden" id="city" value="Montreal" /><input type="hidden" id="line1" value="7043 a rue xxxxxxxx" /><input type="hidden" id="line2" value="apt 8" /><input type="hidden" id="postal_code" value="H2SXXX" />
                    <input type="hidden" id="state" value="Quebec" /><input type="hidden" id="country" value="CA" /><input type="hidden" id="email_address" value="xxxxxxxxx@gmail.com" /><input type="hidden" id="customer_id" value="1" />
                    <style>
                        #stripe_table_new_card #card-element {
                            background-color: #fff;
                            padding: 6px 12px;
                            border: 1px solid #ccc;
                            border-radius: 4px;
                        }
                    </style>
                    <script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script>
                    <script>
                        $(function () {
                            $("[name=checkout_confirmation]").attr("id", "payment-form");
                            var stripe = Stripe("pk_live_qlL9JUxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxo");
                            var elements = stripe.elements();
                            var card = elements.create("card", { hidePostalCode: true });
                            card.mount("#card-element");
                            $("#payment-form").submit(function (event) {
                                var $form = $(this);
                                $form.find("button").prop("disabled", true);
                                var selected = $("input[name='stripe_card']:checked").val();
                                var cc_save = $("[name=card-save]").prop("checked");
                                try {
                                    if ((selected != null && selected != "0") || cc_save) {
                                        updatePaymentIntent(cc_save, selected);
                                    } else {
                                        processNewCardPayment();
                                    }
                                } catch (error) {
                                    $form.find(".payment-errors").text(error);
                                }
                                return false;
                            });
                            if ($("#stripe_table").length > 0) {
                                if (typeof $("#stripe_table").parent().closest("table").attr("width") == "undefined") {
                                    $("#stripe_table").parent().closest("table").attr("width", "100%");
                                }
                                $("#stripe_table .moduleRowExtra").hide();
                                $("#stripe_table_new_card").hide();
                                $("#card-element").prop("id", "new-card-element");
                                $("#save-card-element").prop("id", "card-element");
                                $('form[name="checkout_confirmation"] input[name="stripe_card"]').change(function () {
                                    if ($(this).val() == "0") {
                                        stripeShowNewCardFields();
                                    } else {
                                        if ($("#stripe_table_new_card").is(":visible")) {
                                            $("#card-element").prop("id", "new-card-element");
                                            $("#save-card-element").prop("id", "card-element");
                                        }
                                        $("#stripe_table_new_card").hide();
                                    }
                                    $('tr[id^="stripe_card_"]').removeClass("moduleRowSelected");
                                    $("#stripe_card_" + $(this).val()).addClass("moduleRowSelected");
                                });
                                $('form[name="checkout_confirmation"] input[name="stripe_card"]:first').prop("checked", true).trigger("change");
                                $("#stripe_table .moduleRow")
                                    .hover(
                                        function () {
                                            $(this).addClass("moduleRowOver");
                                        },
                                        function () {
                                            $(this).removeClass("moduleRowOver");
                                        }
                                    )
                                    .click(function (event) {
                                        var target = $(event.target);
                                        if (!target.is("input:radio")) {
                                            $(this)
                                                .find("input:radio")
                                                .each(function () {
                                                    if ($(this).prop("checked") == false) {
                                                        $(this).prop("checked", true).trigger("change");
                                                    }
                                                });
                                        }
                                    });
                            } else {
                                if (typeof $("#stripe_table_new_card").parent().closest("table").attr("width") == "undefined") {
                                    $("#stripe_table_new_card").parent().closest("table").attr("width", "100%");
                                }
                            }
                            function stripeShowNewCardFields() {
                                $("#card-element").attr("id", "save-card-element");
                                $("#new-card-element").attr("id", "card-element");
                                $("#stripe_table_new_card").show();
                            }
                            function updatePaymentIntent(cc_save, token) {
                                $.getJSON("", { id: $("#intent_id").val(), token: token, customer_id: $("#customer_id").val(), cc_save: cc_save }, function (data) {
                                    if (data.status == "ok") {
                                        var selected = $("input[name='stripe_card']:checked").val();
                                        if (selected == null || selected == "0") {
                                            processNewCardPayment();
                                        } else {
                                            processSavedCardPayment(data.payment_method);
                                        }
                                    } else {
                                        var $form = $("#payment-form");
                                        $form.find("button").prop("disabled", false);
                                        $("#card-errors").text(data.error);
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                            function processNewCardPayment() {
                                stripe
                                    .handleCardPayment($("#secret").val(), card, {
                                        payment_method_data: {
                                            billing_details: {
                                                name: $("#cardholder-name").val(),
                                                address: { city: $("#city").val(), line1: $("#line1").val(), postal_code: $("#postal_code").val(), state: $("#state").val(), country: $("#country").val() },
                                                email: $("#email_address").val(),
                                            },
                                        },
                                    })
                                    .then(function (result) {
                                        stripeResponseHandler(result);
                                    });
                            }
                            function processSavedCardPayment(payment_method_id) {
                                stripe.handleCardPayment($("#secret").val(), { payment_method: payment_method_id }).then(function (result) {
                                    stripeResponseHandler(result);
                                });
                            }
                            function stripeResponseHandler(result) {
                                var $form = $("#payment-form");
                                if (result.error) {
                                    $("#card-errors").text(result.error.message);
                                    $form.find("button").prop("disabled", false);
                                } else {
                                    $("#card-errors").text("Processing");
                                    $form.append($('<input type="hidden" name="stripeIntentId"/>').val(result.paymentIntent.id));
                                    $form.get(0).submit();
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    </script>
                </div>
            </div>
            <table class="table moduleCheckoutConfirmationPaymentInformationCardTable"></table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: I guess that you need to verify that the `stripeToken` exists in `$_POST`. Use `isset` or coalesce operator ??: `$token = isset($_POST['stripeToken'] ? $_POST['stripeToken'] : "";` or with coalesce operator: `$token = $_POST['stripeToken'] ?? "";`

Comment: No it does not work $_POST['stripeToken'] must have a value given by stripe. see above

Comment: Can you share your `<form>` code as well?

Comment: yes see above, tk